# How to Convert Mysql Query into Laravel(Mongodb) Query?

Tags: mongodb, laravel

here, This Query is Perfectly Run in Mysql.
but Overwrite this Query into Laravel(Mongodb) Query Format

```
SELECT F.status, U.username, U.email
FROM users U, friends F
WHERE
CASE

WHEN F.friend_one = '$user_id'
THEN F.friend_two = U.user_id
WHEN F.friend_two= '$user_id'
THEN F.friend_one= U.user_id
END

AND 
F.status='1';
```

this is friend module and get the my all friend list

here is my table look like

```
{
"_id" :"5a12618b82956d4c0e00002d",
"otheruser" : "598442b58ed7bc0c19000029",
"relation_type" : 2,
"is_friend" : "true",
"user_id" : "59bf784682956df00c00002a"
}
```

here is my sample query in repository..

```
  public function GetFriendsOfUser($id,$userId)
   {
         $list = $this->makeModel()
        ->with('getallfrienduser')
         ->where('is_friend',"true")
         ->where('relation_type',2)

        ->where(function ($query) use ($id,$userId) {
                 $query->where('user_id', $userId)
                       ->orWhere('otheruser', $id);
              })
        ->get();
  }
```

here sample join in model and join are sapreated

```
 public function getallfrienduser()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Users','_id','user_id');
  }
  public function getallfriendother()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Users','_id','otheruser');
  }
```

but only one join use(user_id,otheruser) alternatively record find two user.

Comment: how does your mongodb data look like? Are these two separate collections?

Comment: @Astro i already updated my question please give your response 
thanks in advance